# Is the dealer's hand considered soft if he hits himself with an ace?

Tags: blackjack

In Blackjack, is the dealer's hand considered soft if he hits himself with an ace after dealing himself a hand which did not initially have an ace?

To clarify alternatively, is it only soft if his initial hand has an ace or is it *always* soft so long as he acquires an ace at any point in time (other than blackjack of course)?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.readybetgo.com/blackjack/strategy/soft-17-rule-2496.html):

> Any blackjack hand that contains an ace counted as an 11 is a soft hand.

So it does not matter when the ace entered the hand.

Comment: There are enough variations out there though that I can't guarantee this version is universal - does anyone else know more?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is yes, a total arrived at with an ace counted as 11 is a "soft total,."

This comes into play with the ["soft seventeen"](http://www.readybetgo.com/blackjack/strategy/soft-17-rule-2496.html) rule that reduces a player's expectation slightly (by 0.2%). This happens with a hand if a 1 makes it a 7, and an 11 makes it a 17. (The two starting cards might have been 3-3, 4-2, or 5-A).

Normally, a dealer needs to stand on a "hard" 17. With a "soft 17," that includes an ace, s/he must redraw, and possibly make a hand higher than 17. This increases the dealer's chance of beating a player who hasn't busted.

If a player has starting cards totalling 11 or higher (e.g. 7-4), an A makes it a "hard" 12, because if you count the A as an 11, the player busts.